# COCOAPODS INSTALLATION - Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) (Gem::MissingSpecError) via brew / ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) via gem

Tags: react-native, macos, rubygems, cocoapods, homebrew

I am running a mobile development on react native. After installing a package, I start getting error that some module isn't found on pod. So I decided to update the whole package.json with a new modules after several unsuccessful research attempts. But when  try the pod re-installation, the issue still persist.

So I decided to update pod itself via brew, but it was not successful. Despite I also uninstall and install, it was still same

Other things I attempted is to update gem and rvm, on which i try to install the cocoapods and the result is no difference

list of commands I tried different times

```
sudo gem install cocoapods 

gem install cocoapods --user-install

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4

brew install cocoapods
```

Here is my .bash_profile

```
....
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

source $(dirname $(gem which colorls))/tab_complete.sh
alias lc='colorls'
```

VIA BREW

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        16: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
        15: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path'
        14: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize'
        13: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:286:in `block in activate_bin_path'
        12: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1398:in `activate'
        11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `activate_dependencies'
        10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `each'
         9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `block in activate_dependencies'
         8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1398:in `activate'
         7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `activate_dependencies'
         6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `each'
         5: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `block in activate_dependencies'
         4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1398:in `activate'
         3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `activate_dependencies'
         2: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `each'
         1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1428:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 41 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/mac/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec' , execute `gem env` for more information
        16: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
        15: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path'
        14: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize'
        13: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:286:in `block in activate_bin_path'
        12: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1398:in `activate'
        11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `activate_dependencies'
        10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `each'
         9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `block in activate_dependencies'
         8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1398:in `activate'
         7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `activate_dependencies'
         6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `each'
         5: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `block in activate_dependencies'
         4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1398:in `activate'
         3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `activate_dependencies'
         2: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1416:in `each'
         1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1427:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1430:in `rescue in block in activate_dependencies': Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 41 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/mac/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec' at: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/specifications/activesupport-6.1.5.gemspec, execute `gem env` for more information
```

VIA GEM

```
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/mac/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/mac/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/CHANGELOG.md
Sylvester @ sudo gem install cocoapods --user-install
Password:
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/mac/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/mac/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20220625-94173-1we5ltp.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:10:in `system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/mac/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mac/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mac/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out
```

Please help me I am stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by simply opening the terminal via Visual Studio Code and this displays the required Ruby for my Mac. Like this:

```
rvm install "ruby-2.7.4”

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And everything worked!